# Python function: return list of lists, and simple list --> ValueError (too many values to unpack)

Tags: python, list, function, return, return-type

I have a Python function (`'extract features'`) that should return two elements. The first element is a list of lists: `feat_values = [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]`. The second element is a simple list: `feat_names = [1, 2, 3]`.

The function ends with:

```
return feat_values, feat_names
```

I call this function as follows:

```
feat_values, feat_names = list(map(extract_features, train_data.data))
```

However, I then get the 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call

```
feat_values, feat_names = list(map(extract_features, train_data.data))
```

maps your function onto the training data and, thus, returns a list of pairs (those are returned by each call to your function): one such pair for each element in the data. What you are probably trying to achieve is:

```
feat_values, feat_names = zip(*map(extract_features, train_data.data))
```

which transposes the (long) list of pairs into two lists of the first and second elements of those pairs respectively.

Comment: `zip` expects multiple arguments. The `*` "unpacks" the single iterator (list in Python2) that is returned by `map` and passes its elements to zip as multiple arguments. See these [docs on that topic](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).